# how to make specific textures for nbt tags

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Let s say  we have stone sword with no NBT tags (we want it to look normally). And let s say we want to make another stone sword with NBT tag "lol". We want the "lol sword" look like cucumber while the sword with no tags looks like a normal sword. My question is how to get this done (if it s possible).

Thank you

Comment: I don't think that is possible as of now, but there is a suggestion like this on the [minecraft forum](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-discussion/suggestions/76702-swappable-textures-for-items-and-blocks-via-nbt).

Comment: thnx for saying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is possible by disabling durability. And making a  separate texture for multiple durability variants of the same item. Sorry I didn't realize this.